# How to loop with in xslt and skip other values if particular value found

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have sample xml like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <File>
    <Detail>
     <Employee>1234</Employee>
   <Salary_Plan>B</Salary_Plan>
   <Amount>001</Amount>
   </Detail>
 <Detail>
     <Employee>1234</Employee>
   <Salary_Plan>C</Salary_Plan>
   <Amount>002</Amount>
   </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <Employee>1234</Employee>
      <Salary_Plan>A</Salary_Plan>
      <Amount>003</Amount>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
     <Employee>ABC</Employee>
   <Salary_Plan>C</Salary_Plan>
   <Amount>003</Amount>
   </Detail>
</File>
```

Employee "1234" contains three plans A,B,C,so this employee as plan A exists in file, we need to skip remaining two plan rows 
For employee  with unique plan  there is no restrictions

Output need to display as :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <File>
        <Employee>ABC</Employee>
       <Plan>C</Plan>
       <Amount>003</Amount>
       </Row>
        <Row>
         <Employee>1234</Employee>
       <Plan>A</Plan>
       <Amount>001</Amount>
       </Row>
    </File>

    How can we achieve this in xslt 2.0
```

Comment: It sounds like a grouping problem where you want to output only one `Plan` for any `Row` group of a certain `Employee`. So see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for an intro or your favourite XSLT tutorial.

Comment: I am able to do  group by employee id but need to know how can we eliminate after grouping

Comment: if any sample xslt code is really helpful

Comment: If you have the grouping then show us that code, then we can extend/fix it, in case of XSLT 2/3 you would simply process `.` or `./Plan` inside the `xsl:for-each-group` as there you process the first item in each group as the context item.

Comment: I am able to group by employees distinct and duplicates but not combination of both in my case output need to show only distinct employees and if one employee contains  multiple rows in xml with multiple sample plans  it need to sort plans and show  distinct row on that particular  employee based on only one plan and elimate remaining plan rows of that particular employee ..so i am struggling to  do xslt loop and elimanation of rows..so if any sample code really helpful

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate the version of XSLT you use/can use and show us the XSLT you have to group.

Comment: <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each-group select="/File/Detail" group-by="Employee" >
            <xsl:sort select="Employee"></xsl:sort>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <Employee><xsl:value-of select="Employee"/></Employee>
                <Salary_Plan><xsl:value-of select="Salary_Plan"/></Salary_Plan>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I don't see any `Detail` element in the sample XML you have in your question so `select="/File/Detail"` doesn't seem to make any sense in that context. But in general, if you use `xsl:for-each-group` and only want to output one item for each group you simply create that one item, for instance copying the context item `.` or `current-group()[1]`. If you use `xsl:for-each select="current-group()"` you of course don't eliminate duplicates, you output them all. So drop that.

Comment: yes due to space constraint i eliminated in the code for the above code the output is coming as   1234  B  1234  C  1234  A  456  C  now my requirment is as employee1234  contains 3 plans we need to keep A and eliminate remaining two plans similary if employee 1234 contains two plans B and c we need to keep B and eliminate C plan for that employee

Comment: You should edit your question to show any code samples in a well-formatted manner.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track.

In the foreach for the employe salary plans you need to sort by `Salary_Plan` and add a condition to keep your plan A first (or B if it's the first plan).

With this **xslt** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <File>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="/File/Detail" group-by="Employee" >
                <xsl:sort select="Employee"/>
                <Row>
                    <Employee>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </Employee>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <!-- Sort by Salary_Plan -->
                        <xsl:sort select="Salary_Plan"/>
                        <!-- Keep first plan -->
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                            <Plan>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Salary_Plan"/>
                            </Plan>
                            <Amount>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                            </Amount>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Row>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your output will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File>
    <Row>
        <Employee>1234</Employee>
        <Plan>A</Plan>
        <Amount>003</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Employee>ABC</Employee>
        <Plan>C</Plan>
        <Amount>003</Amount>
    </Row>
</File>
```